# Values of $x>0$ of a curve

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I got the following task:

> A curve has the equation 
>   $$ 
> y = x^{\frac{3}{2}} + \frac{48}{x} 
> $$ 
>   for values of $x > 0$.
>
> Find the coordinates of the turning point of the curve.
>
> By considering the second derivative determine whether this turning point
>   is a maximum or minimum.

My attempts:

$$
y = \frac{x^3}{2} + \frac{48}{x} \implies \frac{x^3}{2} + 48x^{-1}
$$

Turning points when $\frac{dy}{dx}=0$

$$
\frac{3x^2}{2} - 48x^{-2}=0
$$

$$
\frac{3x^2}{2} - \frac{48}{x^2} = 0 \implies \frac{3x^4}{2} - 48 = 0 \implies 3x^4=96
$$

$x^4 = 32$ when $x=\sqrt[4]{32}$

$$
\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} \implies 3x + 96x^{-3} \ldots \quad 
\mbox{i.e.} \,\, 3x + 96/x^3
$$

When, $x = \sqrt[4]{32}, \quad \frac{d^2y}{dx^2} > 0 = \min \mbox{turn}?$

Am I on the right tracks? Also, has anyone got a better layout i could do?

Answer (score 1):

Your are differentiating as if you had $\;\frac{x^3}2\;$ and **not** $\;x^{3/2}\;$ , which is what *actually* appears in that sheet of paper. Thus:

$$\left(x^{3/2}+\frac{48}x\right)'=\frac32x^{1/2}-\frac{48}{x^2}\stackrel ?=0\iff3x^{5/2}=96\implies \color{red}{x=4}\ldots etc.$$

$$\left(x^{3/2}+\frac{48}x\right)''=\frac34x^{-1/2}+\frac{96}{x^3}\stackrel?=0\iff 3x^{5/2}=-384\implies\ldots etc.$$

Comment: Not sure how you got 96 and -364? I'm kinda lost on the question

Comment: He multiplied the equation for $y'$ by $x^2$ re-arranged to $3/2 x^{5/2} = 48$ and then multipled by $2$. Etc.

Comment: I've been looking over this for 2 hours, just don't know how to lay the whole thing out correctly

Comment: @John, what do you mean "to lay out" correctly? It all is differentiation and algebra: $$\frac32x^{1/2}-\frac{48}{x^2}=0\implies \frac32x^{1/2}=\frac{48}{x^2}\implies \frac32x^{5/2}=48\implies x^{5/2}=\frac{48\cdot 2}3=32\implies x^{1/2}=2\implies x=4$$ Remember: we're working with $\;x>0\;$ ...

Answer (score 1):

OK, in more detail:

$$
y = x^{3/2} + \frac{48}{x}
$$

One needs the first and second derivatives for this task, using the rule

$$
\left(x^k\right)' = k \, x^{k - 1}
$$

and the linearity of differentation

$$
\left(a \, f(x) + b \, g(x)\right)' = a \, f'(x) + b \, g'(x)
$$

one gets

$$ 
y' = \frac{3}{2} x^{1/2} - \frac{48}{x^2} \\
y'' = \frac{3}{4} x^{-1/2} + \frac{96}{x^3}
$$

A turning point or rather stationary point occurs where the derivative $y'$ vanishes:

$$
y' = 0 \iff \\
0 = \frac{3}{2} x^{1/2} - \frac{48}{x^2} \iff \\
\frac{3}{2} x^{1/2} = \frac{48}{x^2} \iff \\
x^{1/2} = \frac{32}{x^2} \iff \\
x^{5/2} = 32 \iff \\
x = 32^{2/5} = 2^2 = 4                 
$$

Then one looks at the value of the second derivative $y''$ at that point, or rather the sign of that value:
$$
y'' = \frac{3}{4} 4^{-1/2} + \frac{96}{4^3} > 0
$$

The question was if this is a minimum or maximum, the above shows it is a minimum.

Here is a graph of $f = y, g = y', h = y''$:
[image]